# How to get two element from two dropdown lists (webscraping with python)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to webscrape this webpage ([www.autocar.co.uk](http://www.autocar.co.uk)). Therefore, I would like to select each Automaker in a dropdown menu and the model. I always want to skip the "All models" option.

As I just started coding I would higly appreciate your input!

Desired output:

```
Auto OEM (e.g, Tesla)
   All Models of Tesla (e.g. Model 3, Y...) 

Example:
    Abarth
       595
       595 Competi...
       124 Spider...
       695 Bopisto...
    AC Cars
       #Skip due to no model
```

My code as of now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


#Inputs/URLs to scrape: 
URL = ('https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/tesla')
(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
overview = soup.find()

oems = soup.select('select.car-finder-make-chooser option')                      
for oem_loop in oems[1:]:
    print(oem_loop.text)
    models = soup.select('select.car-finder-model-chooser option')  
    for model_loop in models:
        print(model_loop)
```

My output as of now:

```
Abarth
<option value="0">Model</option>
AC Cars
<option value="0">Model</option>
AC Schnitzer
<option value="0">Model</option>
Aiways
<option value="0">Model</option>
Allard
<option value="0">Model</option>
Alfa Romeo
<option value="0">Model</option>
Alpina
<option value="0">Model</option>
Alpine
<option value="0">Model</option>
Ariel
<option value="0">Model</option>
Ascari
<option value="0">Model</option>
Aston Martin
<option value="0">Model</option>
Audi
<option value="0">Model</option>
BAC
<option value="0">Model</option>
Bentley
<option value="0">Model</option>
Bizzarrini
<option value="0">Model</option>
BMW
<option value="0">Model</option>
Borgward
<option value="0">Model</option>
Bowler
<option value="0">Model</option>
Bugatti
<option value="0">Model</option>
BYD
<option value="0">Model</option>
...
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is your end goal? What information are you ultimately looking to scrape from that website? As it stands now, your question sounds more like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will get you a list of makes, models and their corresponding urls, and it will save a csv file with the details:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.autocar.co.uk/"
s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
full_car_list = []
car_list = [(x.text, x.get("value"), f'https://www.autocar.co.uk/ajax/car-models/{x.get("value")}/0') for x in soup.select_one('#edit-make').select('option')]
for x in car_list:
    r = s.get(x[2])
    try:
        for item in r.json()['options'].items():
            full_car_list.append((x[0], item[1], f'https://www.autocar.co.uk{item[0]}'))
    except Exception as e:
        full_car_list.append((x[0], 'no models', f'https://www.autocar.co.uk/vehicles/{x[0]}'))
cars_df = pd.DataFrame(full_car_list[1:], columns = ['Make', 'Model', 'Url'])
cars_df = cars_df[cars_df.Model != 'All models']
cars_df.to_csv('makes_models.csv')
print(cars_df.head(15))
```

This will return a csv file, and will print the head of the dataframe:

```
Make    Model   Url
1   Abarth  595 https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/abarth/595
2   Abarth  595 Competizione    https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/abarth/595-competizione
3   Abarth  124 Spider 2016-2019    https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/abarth/124-spider-2016-2019
4   Abarth  695 Biposto 2015-2016   https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/abarth/695-biposto-2015-2016
5   AC Cars no models   https://www.autocar.co.uk/vehicles/AC Cars
7   AC Schnitzer    ACS3 Sport  https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/ac-schnitzer/acs3-sport
8   AC Schnitzer    ACS1    https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/ac-schnitzer/acs1
9   AC Schnitzer    ACS5 Sport  https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/ac-schnitzer/acs5-sport
10  Aiways  no models   https://www.autocar.co.uk/vehicles/Aiways
12  Allard  J2X MkII    https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-review/allard/j2x-mkii
[...]
```

I suggest going over the documentation for bs4:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Also for pandas:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

And also for python requests:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is super valueable input. Can I ask you for one more favor? To scrape the model pages, I only need the url in a for loop. I do not want to have this in an array format, but in a for loop with 1 variable. Is that something you can help me with? :)

Comment: If the response above addressed your (original) question, then accept it. If you have further questions, then post them as new questions.

Comment: Okay. i thougt it makes sense to follow up here rather than posting the same question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73137154/how-to-get-url-from-two-dropdown-lists-webscraping-with-python

Comment: Responded to it as well. Why did you removed the `cars_df = cars_df[cars_df.Model != 'All models']` line? That is actually removing the unwanted information from your results.